# Fetching data from entity using nspredicate

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I have core data entity called "Songs" which contains details of different songs details. One of the attribute of this entity is "Language". I want to fetch all songs with Language Spanish. But if number of songs with Spanish is zero, then it should fetch all songs with default language, thats english. Is this possible through single NSPredicate if I know default language and needed language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    //here strLanguage is string with the name of selected language
    NSPredicate * predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Language == %@",strLanguage]; 
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSMutableArray* mutableFetchCategory = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

if ([mutableFetchCategory count] > 0) 
    {

        for (NSManagedObject *info in mutableFetchCategory)
        {
             NSLog(@"%@",info);
             //Extract data from  each "info" object and store it in an array and display it in tableview
        }
}

else

{
    // Repeat the same code [or u can use functions for reusability] with language "English".
}
```

You can also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020104/fetching-core-data-values-using-predicate)